# Use Telerik ComboBox in WPF default DataGrid as DataTemple Column binding problem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, radcombobox

I prepared a WPF `DataGrid` and want to use a `RadComboBox` in a template column but the `ItemsSource` binding for MVVM does not work.

Is there any solution for that?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Grades}"  />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <telerik:RadComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Grades}"   />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Grades` is a collection property in your data grid items, remove `DataContext`.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Grades}"/>
```

If you have Telerik controls anyway, why not use its data grid equivalent [`RadGridView`](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/overview2) directly? It will automatically use its own `RadComboBox` control if you [create a combo box column](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/columntypes/column-types-combobox-column) in it, e.g.:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
      <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Grades"
                                      DataMemberBinding="{Binding SelectedGrade}"
                                      ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding Grades}"/>
   </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

As a notice, you must have a property like `SelectedGrade` that stores the selected combo box item in your item type, because if you do not set a `DataMemberBinding`, the column will not show anything.